# router.prefetch is not a function , Unable to check submit function in react testing library

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-router, next.js, react-testing-library

This is my test code for a component, in which I need to check either a form submit function gets called or not.

```
import React from 'react'
import { render, screen, fireEvent, debug } from '@testing-library/react'
import '@testing-library/jest-dom'
import * as nextRouter from 'next/router'
nextRouter.useRouter = jest.fn()
nextRouter.useRouter.mockImplementation(() => ({ route: '/' }))
import Locations from '../pages/settings/locations'
import Add from '../pages/settings/locations/add'
import { act } from 'react-dom/test-utils'

describe('Add Locations', () => {
nextRouter.useRouter.mockImplementation(() => ({ route: '/settings/locations/add', pathname: '/settings/locations/add' })); // or which pathname you want to test
let companies = [
    {
        "name": "Fake Company Express",
        "phone": "9876543210",
        "email": "test@company.com",
        "contact": "Test",
        "address1": "Fake address1",
        "address2": "Fake address2",
        "address3": "",
        "city": "Fake City",
        "zip": "123456",
        "state": "State",
        "country": "Demo Test",
        "UUID": "9d8616dd-4689-4689-8812-a2345ccdcfc5"
    }
]

it('validate before save add location data', async () => {
        const mockAdd = jest.fn()
        const {getByLabelText, getByRole} = render(<Add data={companies} addLocation={mockAdd} />)

        const addButton = screen.getByTestId('addLocationBtn')

        await act(async () => {        

            fireEvent.change(getByRole("textbox", { name: /name/i }), {
                target: { value: "sds" }
            });
            fireEvent.input(getByRole("combobox", { name: /company/i }), {
                target: { value: "sdsd" }
            });
        })  

        await act(async () => {
          fireEvent.click(addButton);
        })
       expect(mockAdd).toHaveBeenCalled() 
  })

})
```

and the Add Component code is:

```
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
export default function Add({...props}) {
   const {
     register,
     handleSubmit,
     formState: { errors },
   } = useForm();

   const addLocation = async (data) => {
        console.log(data)
   }
   ......
   <form className="g-3" onSubmit={handleSubmit(addLocation)} data-testid="addLocationForm">
   <div className="col-md-4  col-lg-4 col-sm-6 mb-3">
     <label htmlFor="" className="form-label">Name</label>
                                                        
     <input type="text" {...register('name', { required: true })} className="form-control" data-testid="name" placeholder="Enter Name Here" />
                                                        {errors.name && <p className="error" role="error" data-testid="name_error">Name is required.</p>}
                                                    
 </div>
 <input type="submit" className="btn btn-primary float-end" value="Save Location" data-testid="addLocationBtn" />
 </form>
}
```

I am using react hook form, getting error as

> TypeError: router.prefetch is not a function

Comment: Where is `next/router` used inside the `Add` component? What action exactly is triggering the error?

Comment: There is no `next/router` used on `Add` component. There is a submit button which's click  is calling save function

Comment: If `next/router` isn't used in that component, why are you mocking it in the tests? And if you _do_ need to mock it for some reason, make sure all the functions it's using are mocked (in this case ensure `router.prefetch` is mocked too).

Comment: const mockAdd = jest.fn()
        const { getByTestId} = render(<Add data={companies} addLocation={mockAdd} />) is used so that it can test that either it has called addLocation function or not. Shouldn't I do this way?

Comment: `addLocation` is an internal function of the component, it's not in your component's props. Rather than testing if it's called, test if it's doing the expected action.

Comment: Can you please suggest the code which should I write for this ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238461/discussion-between-deep-kakkar-and-juliomalves).

Answer (score -1):

Whenever I need to use "next/router" I always call useRouter like this and assign it to a variable:

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router"

const router = useRouter()
```

Maybe this helps

Comment: On which file should I use

Comment: I was thinking the file of your first code block